# Webmethod not returning to AJAX success method when there is more than 100 rows

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

I am populating a grid in JavaScript by calling a webmethod(return json dataset. Dataset contains datatable). Grid is successfully filling when there is less than 100 rows. If there is more rows , it is not returning to Success method of ajax call.

Already tested with breakpoint, break point is coming till return statement in webmethod.

AJAX call:

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'CopyofItemInquiries.aspx/GetUPCDetails',
                data: JSON.stringify({ UPCCollection: UPCCol, UPCLike: UPCLike, UPCRangeFrom: RangeFrom, UPCRangeTo: RangeTo, Filter: FilterVal }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (Result) {
                    var myjsongrid = $.parseJSON(Result.d);
}
});

Web method:

[WebMethod]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "json")]
    public static string GetUPCDetails(List UPCCollection, String UPCLike, String UPCRangeFrom, String UPCRangeTo,String Filter)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary dic_SaveUser = new Dictionary();

```
    var xml = new XElement("ROOT", UPCCollection.Select(x => new XElement("UPCLIST",
                                            new XAttribute("UPC", x))));


    dic_SaveUser.Add("@User_ID", HttpContext.Current.Session["FT_username"]);

    DataSet dt_DataSet = new DataSet("dt_DataSet");
    dt_DataSet = DbAccessModule.getDataTableStoredProcedureForMultipleResultSet((SqlConnection)HttpContext.Current.Session["lt_AppConn"], "sp_UPC_Details", dic_SaveUser);

    HttpContext.Current.Session["VendorDetails"] = dt_DataSet.Tables[1];

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt_DataSet);
}
```

Comment: Can you add an error callback, something like this:   error: function () {console.log("error"); }, double check you're not getting an error?

Comment: Thank you for you response. I added an error method like this error: function (jqXHR, exception) { } and it returned jqXHR.status == 500 . I think its Internal Server Error [500] . How can I find the what the error could be?

Comment: Wrap the WebMethod code in a try-catch would be my first guess, place a break point on the exception. Also, use the debugger to step through the code on the server side and see if it fails in the code.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out this SO question, the JSON payload might be too large - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem solved when I set <configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration> in web config

Comment: No problem good luck with your project